# What are evolutionary reasons for humans' limited regeneration abilities?

Tags: human-biology, evolution, human-evolution, regeneration

As far as I understand (I am not a biologist), a ability of a species arises during the evolution if:

1. It increases reproduction chances
2. It is not too energy expensive
3. It is physically possible

At the same time, if a human loses his/her hand/eye/tooth/almost anything, it won't regrow. However, if such regeneration was possible

1. It would definitely increase reproduction chances, because it would make it much easier to survive (or maybe something even more direct, like reproduction of sexual organs)
2. Ability to regenerate isn't supposed to require any energy until the moment such regeneration is needed (and, therefore, energy spending is justified)
3. It seem to be indeed physically possible, at least for some organs ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regeneration_(biology)) provides examples of species who can regenerate their teeth, body parts (tails) or even lungs)

This seem to be strong reasons why this ability should have been gained during the evolution, but this didn't happen. Why?

Comment: I think the claim #2 (energy) requires more detailed examination of what regeneration involves. Also, the ability to regenerate is rather an exception than a rule among animals, so singling out humans is rather anthropocentric.

Comment: In order to understand limits of evolution of regenerative abilities you must understand the molecular biology of embriogensis including the main genetic players.

https://journals.biologists.com/dev/article/147/14/dev190629/224370/Mechanisms-of-human-embryo-development-from-cell

You should appreciate the complexity of embriogensis! Obviously, this puts enormous constraints on evolution.